# Xcode 12 error - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, react-native

Using xcode 12.5.1 and RN 64.2, my project will not build.

I've reinstalled pods and the project, but cannot get my project to build. Android builds with no problems.

Can anyone help?

```
/Users/apps/myracnative/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: line 27: readlink: command not found
/Users/apps/myracnative/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: line 27: dirname: command not found
/Users/apps/myracnative/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: line 27: cd: : No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```